# Search Bar and button placed improperly in landscape view despite constraints

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.ios, storyboard

I'm trying to add constraints to my button and search bar elements and they work fine in Portrait mode on multiple platforms including ipad, but as soon as I change to landscape view everything brakes and constraints showing conflicts on Iphone's only. Interesting is the fact that Landscape mode on Ipads is completely fine, and works as I imagine it to. I'm new and learning so might have overlooked something, does anyone have any ideas why this weird behavior?

Project has no fancy structure, just pulled up a default single page template on visual studio and dropped a button and SearchBar.

Adding a gif below with the storyboard I'm working on:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Cause:**

Let's take `iPhone 8` as an example:

The size of iPhone 8 is `375 × 667`. In your case, **in Portrait mode**, you set your button vertical spacing to top equals `200`. And you set your button vertical spacing to bottom equals `200`. It's ok because the is still **enough space** for button(button's height is `667-200-200 = 267`).

While **in Landscape mode**, you will found **there is no enough space for button**.(`375-200-200 = -25`). So you get conflicts.

> Landscape mode on Ipads is completely fine, and works as I imagine it
>   to.

This is probably caused by the height of `Ipads` is enough to support the constraints as we know iPad is bigger than iPhone.

**Solution**:

Pay attention to the cause I mentioned above. You can also specify the size of button.

Comment: Thank you! Set different constraints in landscape mode then, and pay attention to element sizing. I was under the impression auto layout and constraints handle the change to landscape mode automatically..